# How to draw a tree in latex?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, forest

[image: ?]
I want to draw this tree in latex but I dont know how to do that, Can someone help me draw this tree in LaTeX? I'm not familiar with it. Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Maybe the [`chains` library](https://tikz.dev/library-chains) is a good starting point? The relevant chapter from the manual (see the link) (and other chapters in the manual, such as [this](https://tikz.dev/tutorial-nodes) one on nodes) shows nicely how to approach such a diagram. Maybe you could first try something and then show where you got stuck. It is much easier to help you this way.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please don't add `forest` just because it is a tree. You've made no attempt to use `forest` to draw it and I'm guessing have no idea how (un)suitable it might be ;). (Trust me, you don't want to do this in `forest` unless somebody else does it for you and they don't want to do it in `forest` either.) You can't have children 180 degrees apart in `forest`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While this is technically a tree, it is visually organized like a matrix which is why I would suggest [TikZ-CD](https://texdoc.org/serve/tikz-cd/0) for it which uses a [TikZ matrix](https://tikz.dev/tikz-matrices) internally.

A TikZ matrix works like a `tabular` or `array` environment where each cell is separated by `&` and each line is separated by `\\`.

However, TikZ-CD adds the `\arrow` (or shorter: `\ar`) macro which specified an line to be drawn between the cells.

Usually, one would write something like `\ar[r]` to specify an arrow to the `r`ight, similarly `l`, `u` and `d` exist (left, up, down). TikZ-CD also provides “shortcuts” for these: `\rar`, `\lar`, `\uar`, `\dar`.

For the small annotations I define the keys `from above`, `from below`, `from left` and `from right` which place an arrow pointing from that direction the the node in that cell. The text on the start of the arrow can the be given inside the quotation marks.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, cd, quotes}
\tikzcdset{
  from direction/.style={
    leftarrow, at end, to path={--++(#1:1em)\tikztonodes}},
  /utils/temp/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
    from #1/.style={start anchor=#2, from direction=#3, #1}},
  /utils/temp/.list={
    below:south:down, above:north:up, left:west:left, right:east:right},
  math mode with extras/.style 2 args={
    math mode=false,
    /tikz/matrix of nodes/.append style={
      execute at begin node={$#1}, execute at end node={#2$}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[
  math mode with extras = \{\},
  arrow style=tikz, sep=1em,
  labels={auto=false, font=\footnotesize},
  arrows={dash, thick},
  cells={nodes={
    circle, draw=red, inner sep=+.2em,
    text width={width("$\{b, c, e\}$")}, align=center}},
  ]
      b, g    \rar \ar[from above, "Root"]
  &   b       \dar                                 \\
  &   b, c    \dar                                 \\
      b, c, e \dar
  &   b, c, e \lar \rar \ar[from below, "Join"]
  &   b, c, e \dar                                 \\
      b, e    \dar
  & & b, e    \dar \ar[from left, "Introduce $b$"] \\
      b       \dar
  & & e       \dar \ar[from left, "Forget $(f)$"]  \\
      a, b    \dar \ar[from right, "Node $i$"]
  & & e, f    \dar                                 \\
      d, a, b \dar
  & & f       \ar[from left, "Leaf"]               \\
      b, d    \rar
  &   d
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Agree. This would be a PITA to do in `forest` (which the question is tagged with for no discernible reason).

Answer (score 5):

A solution using the `chains` library:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, scopes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        thick,
        node distance=5mm,
        every join/.style={
            shorten >=1pt,
            shorten <=1pt,
        },
        every pin/.style={
            font=\small,
            pin edge={
                thick,
                black,
                shorten <=2pt,
                <-
            }
        },
        every on chain/.style={
            join,
            every join/.style=->,
            circle, 
            draw=red, 
            inner sep=3.5pt,
            text width=3.5em, 
            align=center,
            execute at begin node={\(\{},
            execute at end node={\}\)}
        }
    ]
    { [start chain=going right]
        \node[on chain, pin={above:Root}] {b,g};
        \node[on chain] {b};
        \node[on chain, continue chain=going below] {b,c};
        \node[on chain, pin={below:Join}] {b,c,e};
        { [start branch=A going left]
            \node[on chain] {b,c,e};
            \node[on chain, continue chain=going below] {b,e};
            \node[on chain] {b};
            \node[on chain, pin={right:Node $i$}] {a,b};
            \node[on chain] {d,a,b};
            \node[on chain] {b,d};
            \node[on chain, continue chain=going right] {d};
        }
        { [start branch=B going right]
            \node[on chain] {b,c,e};
            \node[on chain, continue chain=going below, pin={left:Introduce $(b)$}] {b,e};
            \node[on chain, pin={left:Forget $(f)$}] {e};
            \node[on chain] {e,f};
            \node[on chain, pin={left:Leaf}] {f};
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]